# .net core 3.1 BackgroundService in console lost the breakpoint and stop ExecuteAsync

Tags: c#, .net-core

If I start the backgroundservice in the console, then if I click mouse on the console, or press the spacebar, the method ExecuteAsync will stop executing.
Program:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console(restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information)
            .WriteTo.File("logs\\log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .CreateLogger();
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {   
                    IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
                    DbConnections options = configuration.GetSection("DbConnections").Get<DbConnections>();
                    services.AddSingleton(options);
                    services.AddHostedService<MailQueueService>();
                }).UseSerilog();
```

Service code:

```
public class MailQueueService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MailQueueService> _logger; 
        private long round = 0;
        public MailQueueService(ILogger<MailQueueService> logger, IConfiguration configuration, DbConnections factory)
        {
            _logger = logger;            
        }
        public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken ct)
        {                    
            _logger.LogWarning($"MailQueueService round #{round} stop at: {DateTimeOffset.Now}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            { 
                 _logger.LogInformation($"MailQueueService start round #{round} at: {DateTimeOffset.Now}");
                round++;
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DelayInseconds), ct);
            }
        }
    }
```

My service needs to run every 15 seconds. Look at the logs, attentive to the time, I clicked on the console with the mouse, and also pressed ESC and the Space.

```
[22:42:25 INF] MailQueueService start round #1 at: 12.10.2020 22:42:25 +03:00
[22:42:30 INF] MailQueueService start round #2 at: 12.10.2020 22:42:30 +03:00
[22:42:35 INF] MailQueueService start round #3 at: 12.10.2020 22:42:35 +03:00
[22:42:40 INF] MailQueueService start round #4 at: 12.10.2020 22:42:40 +03:00 <<<
[22:42:59 INF] MailQueueService start round #5 at: 12.10.2020 22:42:59 +03:00
[22:43:04 INF] MailQueueService start round #6 at: 12.10.2020 22:43:04 +03:00 <<<
[22:43:09 INF] MailQueueService start round #7 at: 12.10.2020 22:43:09 +03:00 <<<
[22:43:14 INF] MailQueueService start round #8 at: 12.10.2020 22:43:14 +03:00
[22:43:20 INF] MailQueueService start round #9 at: 12.10.2020 22:43:20 +03:00
```

If put a breakpoint on the log recording method, then first this place is caught, and after this failure occurs, the point is never caught, the log goes, shows work.

Comment: Console feature.  Press Alt+Spacebar > Properties > Options > untick "QuickEdit mode".

Comment: @Hans Passant It seems to me that there is something more here. It’s not just the output to the console that disappears, but the flow of threads is disrupted.

Comment: It doesn't disappear, output gets paused.  Which causes Console.Write/Line() to stall.  Which causes the thread to stall.  Another way to pause output is typing Ctrl+S.